Adding tailwind class via JS in Livewire component shows in classList but not in dom
I have a livewire component where I'm building an option selector. I'm attempting to add a font-bold tailwind class on click of an element:
@script
<script>
    let options = document.querySelectorAll('.options');
    for (let option of options) {
        boldActive(option);
        updateActive(option);
    }

    function boldActive(option) {
        if (option.ariaSelected === "true") {
            option.classList.add("font-bold");
        }
    }

    function updateActive(option) {
        option.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (this.ariaSelected === "false") {
                console.log(this.classList); // doesn't have "font-bold"

                let currentlySelected = document.querySelector("[aria-selected='true']");

                currentlySelected.ariaSelected = "false";
                currentlySelected.classList.remove("font-bold");

                this.ariaSelected = "true";
                this.classList.add("font-bold");
                console.log(this.classList); // has "font-bold"
            }
        })
    }

</script>
@endscript

The issue that I'm having is that, in the two console logs showing the classList above, the second console log accurately shows that the element has font-bold within its class list, but when I look at the element in the DOM, font-bold hasn't been added! Do I need to do anything in addition to this in order to have the class added to the DOM? Is this some Livewire issue?

Are you sure that this in the event listener is the element to which update the class?
